# Apache Ignite Scala Program brings up Ignite Shell and does not progress

Tags: scala, apache-spark, ignite

This very simple Apache Ignite Scala program is bringing up Ignite Shell and is not progressing further beyond the IgniteContext line ; It just waits, typical of a REPL shell ; What change do I need to make to not bring up Ignite Shell?  All I want to do is store data to ignite cache and then read data from ignite cache from within a scala/spark program ...

```
import org.apache.spark.SparkConf
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext
import org.apache.ignite.spark._
import org.apache.ignite.configuration._

object IgniteIt {

  def main(args: Array[String]) {

    println("\n==========\nIgnite!\n==========\n")

    val cf = new SparkConf().setAppName("Ignite")
    val sc = new SparkContext(cf)

    val igniteContext = new IgniteContext(sc, "cfg/example-cache.xml")

    val cacheRdd: org.apache.ignite.spark.IgniteRDD[Int,String] = igniteContext.fromCache("partitioned")
    val data = Array((1,"One"),(2,"two"),(3,"three"),(4,"four"),(5,"five"))
    val distData = sc.parallelize(data)
    cacheRdd.savePairs(distData)

    val result = cacheRdd.filter(_._2.contains("three")).collect()
    result.foreach(println)

    igniteContext.close(false)

    println("\n==========\nDone!\n==========\n")

  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think, you do not start Ignite.sh before IgniteContest invoked.

You need to do:

```
cd $IGNITE_HOME
bin/ignite.sh
```